# Running into the same error when pulling a new version of the react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

We have a react app on a shared repository. However, for some reason it seems like only one person could work on it. When a person works on the project and pushes a new version, and another one of us pulls and run the new version, we get this error:

```
'react-scripts' not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I know this can be solved if I do `npm install some package`, but the fact that we have to do it every time seems to me something is terribly wrong. Our computers are either Linux or Mac, but I don't think its a OS problem since I can be working on Linux and push new files but my partner also with a Linux runs into the problem. Furthermore, we tried syncing our npm and node versions but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `node_modules` folder checked into the repo by any chance?

Comment: Yes, is it bad practice to include ```node_modules``` in the repo?

Comment: @LikWong Yes. It takes up a ton of space also.

Comment: `node_modules` are not meant to be checked in into repo. If you do this, and use the same repo for Linux and Mac, a lot of things can go wrong. When you do `npm install`, the installer pulls packages for you, and very often some packages get compiled for your platform after the installation. If someone checks in a package compiled for Mac, it will break on Linux. Also, all symbolic links will be broken.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help @euvs

Comment: If it helped, I'll post my comment as an answer then... so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the `node_modules` folder checked-in into your repo.

`node_modules` are not meant to be checked in into the repo. If you do this, and use the same repo for Linux and Mac, a lot of things can go wrong.

When you run `npm install`, the installer pulls packages for you, and very often some packages get compiled for your platform after the installation. If someone checks in a package compiled for Mac, it will break on Linux. Also, all symbolic links will be broken.

Add `node_modules` to gitignore file.